# After ssh, tailf works but cd times out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, linux-networking

I am facing weird issue and not able to continue working on one of my Ubuntu linux machines.

I am able to ssh to my remote Linux machine, and run

```
tailf /var/log/auth.log
```

But server times out and ssh session close with server not responding error if I run

```
cd /var/log
```

The `vi` command is also resulting in same error. `top` command doesn't show anything suspicious. This issue is making the machine unusable. Could anyone please suggest how can I make progress with this issue?

This is happening every time. No issue when connecting via ssh, and no issue with tailf command. As soon as I enter cd command it stop responding.

Thank you so much in advance.

Extra information based on help so far:

1. syslog has no error or failure messages except firewall block messages
2. setting `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1` options didn't change the problem behaviour
3. `strace` log prints messages like `open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
4. `ssh user@host /bin/bash` or `ssh user@host /bin/sh` didn't change problem behaviour

Wondering if there is a way to enable any extra logging to get to the bottom of it.

Thanks so much in advance.

One update I have is that when I accessed the same machine from different network (different ISP), everything worked smoothly. I am not sure if any network issue was involved or not. Weird thing is that it stops responding only when I run a few commands like `cat` or `cd` or `vi`. Commands like `tailf` or `nano` were working alright.

Comment: What does the syslog say (if you can open it)?

Comment: @Sven in one session I did tailf /var/log/syslog, and in another session did cd /var/log. tailf session continued to work and didn't print anything except firewall block messages. Second session disconnected after timeout with 'server not responding' message.

Comment: Hmmm... Are there any other commands that provoke this problem, like `ls -l /var/log`? Are there any `alias`? What does `dmesg` say? Could you try `strace bash 2> /tmp/strace.bash.out` followed by `cd /var/log` and after timeout look at the /tmp/strace.bash.out file?

Comment: If I got it right, your session times out after a certain amount of time? If that is the case you need to `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 $HOST` ( [taken from here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34004/how-does-tcp-keepalive-work-in-ssh]) ).

Comment: @Thomas Earlier I had ServerAliveInterval at 30, so it was disconnecting after 30 seconds. With ServerAliverInterval and ServerAliveCountMax options you mentioned, it is disconnecting within 5 seconds. But it is still disconnecting. Does it mean something is related to session time out?

Comment: @Law29 `ls -l` is working fine, but `cat` command provokes same problem of disconnecting. If I use `nano` then I can see file contents. `dmesg` shows only firewall messages. With `strace`, cd command didn't time out but `cat` command failed. I see a lot of messages like `open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: @Kevin could you add what you have tried so far to your question. This makes the overview a bit easier and people looking at this question do not have to read all the comments, which will become pretty messy...

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in, so the fact that it's timing out is weird, and suggests there's something wrong with either your shell binary or your shell configuration. Suggest trying to SSH with passing the command `/bin/bash` or `/bin/ksh` as part of your SSH command syntax, e.g., `ssh user@host /bin/bash`. This should give you a non-login shell, which will avoid loading a potentially jacked environment. If you still have problems, the issue may be the shell binary.

Comment: @JeremyDover tried `ssh /bin/bash` and `ssh /bin/sh`. After login, I run `cat ./.profile`, and session times out with `server not responding` error message. Everything was working perfectly well. Now, suddenly `cd` command is also not working. Wondering if there is any extra logging that I can enable somewhere

Comment: @Thomas edited the question with summary of suggestions so far. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a `dmesg` after having timed out the `cd` command?

Comment: Do you have any commands run by your shell prompt? `echo $PS1`

Comment: Is your server virtual by any chance? If so, one possible cause for this might be congestion/latency of the hypervisor contacting the datastore where the server disk is stored. If server is physical, it could be an analogous hardware problem. Either way, if you have the sysstat package installed, the output of sar may help you figure out what operations are timing out.